# Using terminal to run java files

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I'm working on a Mac, and use xcode to save my java files. I have a file that runs without error in netbeans. The file has another file in the same folder that acts as the subclass. When I run the file in terminal I suspect that the subclass file is not running because of an multiple can not find symbol errors that come up. Any ideas why? I call the file by using the cd command until I arrive at the folder with the files. I then use the (javac -classpath "filename.java")to run the file.

Comment: `javac -classpath "filename.java"` does not "run" Java files. It invokes the compiler.

Comment: Check your CLASSPATH.  http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html may help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example from my Mac, which might be of some help to you.

List of the files in my directory:

```
$ ls *.java
Child.java   Driver.java  Parent.java
```

Display the contents of all three files:

```
$ cat *.java
// file Child.java
public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child() {
        System.out.println("  I'm the Child...");
    }
}

// file Driver.java
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.hello();
        Child child = new Child();
    }
}

// file Parent.java
public class Parent {
    public Parent() {
    }
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello from the parent.");
    }
}
```

Compile all 3 Java source files into byte code:

```
$ javac *.java
```

Call the Java VM to execute the main entry point:

```
$ java Driver
Hello from the parent.
  I'm the Child...
```

Comment: The ls command was what I needed to at least show that both files were being loaded. I need to go over a list of commands for terminal. Upon compiling the file, I get a note that the file uses unchecked or unsafe operation, which I don't understand since Netbeans doesn't have a problem with it. Asks to recompile with -Xlint. Went a step further and tried calling the java VM but returns a could not find or load main class Driver.

Comment: Did you try compiling with Xlint to see what it says?  It should look like "$ javac -Xlint *.java".

Comment: Here is what Xlint came back with. I'm looking at it now to make heads or tales of it. TotalComp.java:49: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: ArrayList
        ArrayList al1 = new ArrayList();
        ^
  missing type arguments for generic class ArrayList<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class ArrayList