# Running Java files inside a package with a jar library

Tags: java, terminal

Im extremely new to Java so please bear with me.

I would like to run a java project from the terminal.

The directory looks like this :

[image: Code >]

I went on the terminal inside the "src" folder and tried `java InnerFolder.Main` but got the following error msg:

> Error: Could not find or load main class

**How can I run my project?**

**edit:**

compiled files
[image]

Comment: Java is not interpreted. You need to compile the code first.

Comment: Java is a compiled language.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667549/using-terminal-to-run-java-files) for some more details.

Comment: isn't already compiled in the "out" folder though ?

Comment: We don't know - images are impossible to search and guess at.

Comment: @stdunbar you're right let me share that

Comment: `java InnerFolder.Main` should be run at inside `out/production/untitled`.

Comment: Do your Main class and Node class have `package` statements? You'll need to mention the package with `java -cp yourpackage etc`

Comment: @StephenP yes there is package InnerFolder

Comment: @GenoChen seemed to work but im getting an error that I don't ahve when I run the program in intelliJ Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument
 at InnerFolder.Main.main(Main.java:38)

Comment: Based on what you've shown, I believe that you want to `cd Code` and `java -cp pdfbox-app-2.0.24.jar:out`.  But it's not clear if your `.java` files are in the correct package without seeing the code.

Comment: @RogerSteinberg This is because, your code `import`s org.apache.pdfbox..., so you are expected to add the `pdfbox` jar into classpath